# Java to PHP for serial connection (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: java, php, android, arduino, raspberry-pi

I've searched and searched today, but I can't seem to figure out what is wrong here. For background I am using an Android app to communicate via PHP to my RPI and send serial commands to my arduino. For reference I followed [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Control-Raspberry-Pi-GPIO-Using-an-App/?ALLSTEPS) and all applicable instructions in order to create this. My application MainActivity looks like this (with IP changed)

```
package piduinotest.piduinotest;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.piduinotest.piduinotest.R;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;



public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /********************************/
         /*    Define all the buttons    */
        /********************************/

        Button led1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SCW);
        Button led2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SCCW);
        Button led3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SStep);

        /*******************************************************/
         /*  Set an onclick/onchange listener for every button  */
        /*******************************************************/

        led1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    /* button is led 1 */
                    new Background_get().execute("led1=1");
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    new Background_get().execute("led1=0");
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        led2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    /* button is led 2 */
                    new Background_get().execute("led2=1");
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    new Background_get().execute("led2=0");
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        led3.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    /* button is led 3 */
                    new Background_get().execute("led3=1");
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    new Background_get().execute("led3=0");
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }



    /*****************************************************/
       /*  This is a background process for connecting      */
      /*   to the arduino server and sending               */
     /*    the GET request with the added data           */
    /*****************************************************/

    private class Background_get extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                /* Change the IP to the IP you set in the arduino sketch */
                URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.101/index.php" + params[0]);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                    result.append(inputLine).append("\n");

                in.close();
                connection.disconnect();
                return result.toString();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
    }
```

My PHP code located at index.php that is mentioned looks like the following:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
include "php_serial.class.php";

$serial = new phpSerial;
$serial->deviceSet("/dev/ttyACM0");
$serial->confBaudRate(9600);
$serial->confParity("none");
$serial->confCharacterLength(8);
$serial->confStopBits(1);
$serial->deviceOpen();
if (!empty($_GET['led1']==1)){
        $serial-sendMessage("a");
}
elseif (!empty($_GET['led2']==1)){
        $serial-sendMessage("b");
}
elseif (!empty($_GET['led3']==1)){
        $serial-sendMessage("c");
}
else {
$serial->deviceClose();
}

$serial->deviceClose();

?>
```

For whatever reason that seems to elude me, I don't see anything coming through on the serial monitor. I don't see that anything is being passed to the arduino. I can paste any other code that may be helpful, but I am not sure what else that would be. I do have an added button on both sets of code (button C does not exist yet in the arduino program, but I am only pressing a and b, if that makes sense)

What am I missing? I know this is a multi-faceted question, but I am hoping that someone here can see what I am missing.

For reference the errors that I get when executing via cli (which probably don't matter as i am passing nothing) are as follows

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: led1 in /var/www/html/index.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined index: led1 in /var/www/html/index.php on line 14
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: led2 in /var/www/html/index.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined index: led2 in /var/www/html/index.php on line 17
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: led3 in /var/www/html/index.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined index: led3 in /var/www/html/index.php on line 20
```

Also the output from Android Studio is showing me the following

```
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1436)
I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath caller 
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/piduinotest.piduinotest-1/lib/arm64
I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is piduinotest.piduinotest, real application class is null.
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/piduinotest.piduinotest-1/lib/arm64
D/InjectionManager: InjectionManager
D/InjectionManager: fillFeatureStoreMap piduinotest.piduinotest
I/InjectionManager: Constructor piduinotest.piduinotest, Feature store :{}
I/InjectionManager: featureStore :{}
W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/piduinotest.piduinotest-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in piduinotest.piduinotest rsrc of package piduinotest.piduinotest
W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/piduinotest.piduinotest-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in piduinotest.piduinotest rsrc of package piduinotest.piduinotest
D/Activity: performCreate Call Injection manager
I/InjectionManager: dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : piduinotest.piduinotest.MainActivity isFragment :false
D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : SecSettings2
D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{45576f0 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so
D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x7f96f6b178
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4

                  [ 11-27 20:08:59.802 15445:15709 D/         ]
                  ro.exynos.dss isEnabled: 0
D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1440x2560]-format:1
D/libGLESv1: DTS_GLAPI : DTS is not allowed for Package : piduinotest.piduinotest
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 84 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 84 - 0, 1127) or=1
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@e621a30 time:752185528
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED: ci=Rect(0, 84 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 84 - 0, 0) or=1
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://10.238.203.202/index.phpled1=1
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:242)
W/System.err:     at piduinotest.piduinotest.MainActivity$Background_get.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:99)
W/System.err:     at piduinotest.piduinotest.MainActivity$Background_get.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:91)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.168.1.101/index.phpled1=0
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:242)
W/System.err:     at piduinotest.piduinotest.MainActivity$Background_get.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:99)
W/System.err:     at piduinotest.piduinotest.MainActivity$Background_get.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:91)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.168.1.101/index.phpled2=1
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:242)
W/System.err:     at piduinotest.piduinotest.MainActivity$Background_get.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:99)
W/System.err:     at piduinotest.piduinotest.MainActivity$Background_get.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:91)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.168.1.101/index.phpled2=0
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:242)
W/System.err:     at piduinotest.piduinotest.MainActivity$Background_get.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:99)
W/System.err:     at piduinotest.piduinotest.MainActivity$Background_get.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:91)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.168.1.101/index.phpled1=1
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:242)
W/System.err:     at piduinotest.piduinotest.MainActivity$Background_get.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:99)
W/System.err:     at piduinotest.piduinotest.MainActivity$Background_get.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:91)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@e621a30 time:752193855
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://10.238.203.202/index.phpled1=0
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:242)
W/System.err:     at piduinotest.piduinotest.MainActivity$Background_get.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:99)
W/System.err:     at piduinotest.piduinotest.MainActivity$Background_get.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:91)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: 1. Spell out (RPI) - I know you mean Raspberry Pi but it also refers to an engineering school in the United States. 2. Did you look at the `url` string in `Background_get`. My guess is that it looks like `http://192.168.1.101/index.phpled3=0` which isn't valid http syntax. As always try each component in isolation to make sure each part works before putting them all together.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured this out. The first problem I had was the string for the connection. Where I had originally posted

```
 URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.101/index.php" + params[0]);
```

it should have been this

```
 URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.101/?" + params[0]);
```

This allowed the parameters to be passed. The second problem that I had was that the php statements were incorrect. I modified it to the following

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
include "php_serial.class.php";

$serial = new phpSerial;
$serial->deviceSet("/dev/ttyACM0");
$serial->confBaudRate(9600);
$serial->confParity("none");
$serial->confCharacterLength(8);
$serial->confStopBits(1);
$serial->deviceOpen();
if (isset($_GET['led1'])){
        if($_GET['led1']==1){
        $serial->sendMessage("a");
}}

elseif (isset($_GET['led2'])){
        if($_GET['led2']==1){
        $serial->sendMessage("b");
}}
elseif (isset($_GET['led3'])){
        if($_GET['led3']==1){
        $serial->sendMessage("c");
}}


$serial->deviceClose();

echo "I've sent a message! \n\r";
?>
```

I hope this helps those who are trying to accomplish the same thing. Currently this is working as designed. Android application is able to send commands via php page to the arduino connected via serial.